# How to find the minimum battery capacity C needed for the drone to reach the landing point?

Tags: quadcopter, battery

I calculated the height object height, Distance to the base of the object, Drone weight, maximum and minimum battery voltage, resistance force and power ($P$).
The drone is flying in steady state, without acceleration and flying on a straight trajectory.
I started looking for formulas on the Internet and came across this one:

$U_{max}=U_{min}−\frac{Q_{max}}{C}$

$Q_{max}$ is the maximum charge of the battery that it can give from a fully charged state to a fully discharged one. And the problem is that I can't find the formula for $Q_{max}$. The formulas I found were through the minimum battery capacity $C$. I may be an idiot, but I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: It's not my homework. I can't find a formula to calculate

Comment: To find Qmax you need to know C, but i need to find it

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* xCrane. Even though you say it isn't, this does look like a homework question, so I can understand peoples confusion. On stack exchange, questions like this should include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve/understand the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving/understanding it. Please edit your question to add this information and take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: To many variables you haven't accounted for... starting and ending elevation above sea level, head wind, tail wind, ambient temperature, blade pitch, is the drone in ground effect, thermals. That being said check out https://ecalc.ch.